# how to check for an array update

Tags: c++, arrays, memory

I have an array of some data type (int, string, or even user defined class objects) and several threads in my program. I want to be able to find if the array has been updated after it was initialized with some values. One idea is to associate the hash of values in the array and whenever I want to check if the array has been updated, recalculate the hash. Is there any other way of doing it in c++ ? or can we check if the range of memory address has been updated since we last checked or not?

Thanks

Comment: It depends on so many things.. 1) do you have the access to the code that modifies it? If not, then 2) How frequently it's modified, how frequently do you want to perform these checks and how large is it? Oh, and why do you need it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could encapsulate the array in a class template that provides a facade for whatever read and write ops you need, and also marks the array `dirty` when it's updated - reset the `dirty` flag on each inspection.

Not sure how you make this reliable across multiple reader/writer threads but I guess it depends on access pattern and the exact semantics you want.

[Hashing won't work because hashes can always collide.]

Comment: A more sophisticated solution would allow interested parties (Observers) to register a callback so that every change to the array data (Observable) results in immediate notification (Observer pattern).  But this seems like overkill, again it's hard to say from the limited info here.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try implement this.

Answer (score 3):

The hash approach only works if you don't care about the case where an object is modified but then reset back to its initial value.  In this case, the object was "updated," but there's no way to tell using a hash.

Another approach is to use an update counter:  keep an integer alongside the object and increment it every time you update.

Comment: I am fine with the object being modified but reset back to the same. Wat would be a good hash function which can work on all possible data types..a templated hash function? Also, update counter will not work with string, int, etc.

Comment: @user352951: you can't write "a good hash function [for] all possible data types"... at the very least you need some indication of which bits partake in the logical value - i.e. ignoring padding and (likely mutable) cache data etc..  You also need to make some decisions about equivalence (i.e. with some data types, there may be multiple representations of the same logical value, or you may need - for your purposes - to consider some logical values equivalent (e.g. +0 and -0).